# Converted MVC app to Azure Cloud Service Project - cant get latest

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-roles

I converted an MVC5 app to an Azure Cloud service project and it created the Azure project (used this page for instructions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh420322.aspx#ProjectTemplates
)
I checked in the newly added project to TFS by right-clicking the project and selecting Check-in.  When I tried to get latest from another dev machine, the Azure project does not show up in the solution explorer.   What am I missing?  Does each dev machine need to create the Azure project independently?   I can see the files in TFS and they were copied down to my local drive, but the project doesn't show up under the solution.

thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to checkin the changes to the sln file also, and ensure your workspace mapping includes the solution file.